# Find port of RFID reader

Tags: linux, serial-port, usb, rfid, libusb

I am using pyembedded in for a Python program using Ubuntu 22.04.

I am trying to get the ID that the RFID reader should provide when it reads a card. By using pyembedded I need to specify the port of the RFID using this line of code:

```
rfid = RFID(port='{USB}', baud_rate=9600)
```

I cannot find the actual USB port that is in use the RFID. Here is the `udevadm info`:

```
sudo udevadm info --query=all  --name=/dev/input/event16
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/0003:2518:6022.0003/input/input21/event16
N: input/event16
L: 0
S: input/by-id/usb-NSCCN_wCopy_Smart_Reader-event-if00
S: input/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:2:1.0-event
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/0003:2518:6022.0003/input/input21/event16
E: DEVNAME=/dev/input/event16
E: MAJOR=13
E: MINOR=80
E: SUBSYSTEM=input
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=1191291401
E: ID_INPUT=1
E: ID_VENDOR=NSCCN
E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=NSCCN
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=2518
E: ID_MODEL=wCopy_Smart_Reader
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=wCopy\x20Smart\x20Reader
E: ID_MODEL_ID=6022
E: ID_REVISION=0103
E: ID_SERIAL=NSCCN_wCopy_Smart_Reader
E: ID_TYPE=hid
E: ID_BUS=usb
E: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:030000:
E: ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
E: ID_USB_DRIVER=usbhid
E: ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:2:1.0
E: ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_14_0-usb-0_2_1_0
E: LIBINPUT_DEVICE_GROUP=3/2518/6022:usb-0000:00:14.0-2
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/input/by-id/usb-NSCCN_wCopy_Smart_Reader-event-if00 /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:2:1.0-event
```

Is it specified here somewhere the path of the USB port in use and I cannot see it?

I also tried multiple ways so far, but none of the seemed to be working. I added also an udev rule containing the vendor and product ID of the RFID that looks like this:
SUBSYSTEM=="USB", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2518", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6022", MODE="0660", GROUP="plugdev"

Here is the full device info that I get using `usb.core`:

```
DEVICE ID 2518:6022 on Bus 001 Address 007 =================
 bLength                :   0x12 (18 bytes)
 bDescriptorType        :    0x1 Device
 bcdUSB                 :  0x110 USB 1.1
 bDeviceClass           :    0x0 Specified at interface
 bDeviceSubClass        :    0x0
 bDeviceProtocol        :    0x0
 bMaxPacketSize0        :   0x40 (64 bytes)
 idVendor               : 0x2518
 idProduct              : 0x6022
 bcdDevice              :  0x103 Device 1.03
 iManufacturer          :    0x1 NSCCN
 iProduct               :    0x2 wCopy Smart Reader
 iSerialNumber          :    0x3 
 bNumConfigurations     :    0x1
  CONFIGURATION 1: 400 mA ==================================
   bLength              :    0x9 (9 bytes)
   bDescriptorType      :    0x2 Configuration
   wTotalLength         :   0x29 (41 bytes)
   bNumInterfaces       :    0x1
   bConfigurationValue  :    0x1
   iConfiguration       :    0x0 
   bmAttributes         :   0xc0 Self Powered
   bMaxPower            :   0xc8 (400 mA)
    INTERFACE 0: Human Interface Device ====================
     bLength            :    0x9 (9 bytes)
     bDescriptorType    :    0x4 Interface
     bInterfaceNumber   :    0x0
     bAlternateSetting  :    0x0
     bNumEndpoints      :    0x2
     bInterfaceClass    :    0x3 Human Interface Device
     bInterfaceSubClass :    0x0
     bInterfaceProtocol :    0x0
     iInterface         :    0x0 
      ENDPOINT 0x81: Interrupt IN ==========================
       bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
       bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
       bEndpointAddress :   0x81 IN
       bmAttributes     :    0x3 Interrupt
       wMaxPacketSize   :   0x40 (64 bytes)
       bInterval        :    0x1
      ENDPOINT 0x2: Interrupt OUT ==========================
       bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
       bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
       bEndpointAddress :    0x2 OUT
       bmAttributes     :    0x3 Interrupt
       wMaxPacketSize   :   0x40 (64 bytes)
       bInterval        :    0x1
```

Also, when I am running:

```
rfid = RFID(port='/dev/bus/usb/001/009', baud_rate=9600)
```

I get:

```
serial.serialutil.SerialException: Could not configure port: (25, 'Inappropriate ioctl for device')
```

From where can I get the path of the port in use by this device?

Answer (score 0):

From pyembedded [website](https://pypi.org/project/pyembedded/):

*Note: Use port as ‘COM1’, ‘COM2’ etc in case of windows machine. Use port as ‘/dev/ttyUSB0’ in case of linux based devices:*

I suppose you are taking /dev/bus/usb/001/009 from the `lsusb` command output. Check this question(https://askubuntu.com/questions/435861/what-is-the-difference-between-dev-tty-and-dev-bus-usb-001-002) to understand the difference between both paths.

I should use `dmesg` and connect/disconnect the device to see how Linux is managing the rfid reader. Then if the reader is being mapped to a tty you can use the path to call  `RFID(port, baud_rate)`

Comment: What if it's not mapped to a tty?

Comment: Well, in that case you'll need to find a driver for the RFID reader. Then install it and connect the reader. What is the output of dmesg?